# Cakephp 2.5.2 installation requirements

Tags: cakephp, installation, requirements

It may be unusual to ask for requirements as it's common to find this kind of information on the developers pages. But in this case I'm in doubt if there can be 'undefined' requirements.

Let's see what I've got.

I prepared a complete setup including the DebugKit as you can see on the first image.

Then, totally in accordance with the manuals, i prepared 2 tables, and 'baked all'.

The second image shows a screenshot of the output of the users/index.ctp on my local machine and on another server where everything runs normal.

But, after uploading this to the server where I expect to host the site I got lots of errors and undefined index messages. See the output on the third image.

I have to mention that the server works with PHP 5.3.28 and pdo_enabled and that I've copied all files to the /public_html folder so that there are no special rooting requirements.

So my questions: Are there other requirements to have cakephp 2.5.2 running? What can cause the malfunction?

Many thanks for any hint

[first image http://cakephp252.96.lt/img/cwdinstallconfirm.png](http://cakephp252.96.lt/img/cwdinstallconfirm.png)

[second image http://cakephp252.96.lt/img/cupusers.png](http://cakephp252.96.lt/img/cupusers.png)

[failure http://cakephp252.96.lt/img/cwdusers.png](http://cakephp252.96.lt/img/cwdusers.png)

Comment: What's the Mysql version on the server which shows these errors?

Comment: @ADmad MySql Client API version  5.1.68